# Find the volume of a body in the first octant.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the region in the first octant bounded by $y^2 = 4-x$ and $y = 2z$ using double integral. Is there a mistake in the statement of the problem? When I evaluate the integral I am getting different answers with different orders of integration. Also, I am having hard time visualizing what kind of body this would be. 
Can anybody help me figure it out?

**EDIT:**

I think I got it figured out. The volume $V$ came out to be $\iint_D \dfrac{y}{2}dA$, where $D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x+y^2\leq 4\}$. After evaluating it as an iterated integral, I got 2 which matches the correct answer. 
But this became apparent only after I sketched the regions by hand. So I was wondering if it's possible to figure out the region without looking at the plots. For instance, it is not immediately clear from the given constraints that in the end $(x,y)$ must satisfy $x+y^2\leq 4$.

Comment: The statement of the problem looks fine to me. Why don't you show us your work so far -- setting up the integral -- and maybe we can help more. You can click on "edit", just below your posting, to fill in details for us.

Answer (score 0):

The question starts with "Find the volume of the region in the first octant", so we get the following restrictions:

$$x>0$$
$$y>0$$
$$z>0$$

Next, we look at the part which says: "bounded by $y^2=4−x$ and $y=2z$".

This gives us further clues about the range of $x, y$ and $z$.

Given some value of $x$, the range of $y$ is $$0<y<\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

Given some value of $y$, the range of $z$ is $$0<z<\frac{y}{2}$$

So, we get the following range of $x$, $y$ and $z$: $$0<2z<y<\sqrt{4-x^2}$$

Also, since $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ has to be a well defined quantity, we get the range of $x$ to be $$0<x<2$$

Finally, we can evaluate the value of the integral as follows:

$$V = \int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{4-x^2} \int_0^\frac{y}{2} dzdydx$$

or, as the EDIT points out,

$$V = \int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{4-x^2} \frac{y}{2} dydx$$

We evaluate $V=2$.

Comment: this does not answer the question. How exactly do you know it cannot be $\sqrt{4-x^2}<y<2z$, just by looking at the equation? It only become apparent after sketching the region or used some sort of graphing aid.